# How to click within the checkbox as per the HTML through Selenium Python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors

Hi guys i was trying to click this checkbox :

```html
<label class="has-checkbox terms"><input name="order[terms]" type="hidden" value="0" /><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" name="order[terms]" id="order_terms" />I have read and agree to the <a href="http://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/terms">terms & conditions</a>, and accept the return policy<span class="terms-error">please agree to the terms</span></label></p><div class="g-recaptcha" data-callback="checkoutAfterCaptcha" data-sitekey="AAAA3423" data-size="invisible"></div><input id="number_v" name="hpcvv" /></fieldset></div></div><div id="cart-footer"><div id="pay"><p style="">Surgelati</p><input type="submit" name="commit" value="process payment" class="button checkout" disable_with="processing, please wait..." /><a class="button cancel" href="http://www.altervista.com/shop">cancel</a></div></div></form></div><div id="surchage_info_tooltip">Vendita
```

I have tried with :

```html
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

element = driver.find_element_by_id("order_terms")

actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(element).perform()
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
element = driver.find_element_by_id('order_terms').click()

driver.find_element_by_class_name("has-checkbox terms").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[contains(text(), 'I have read and agree to the')]").click()
```

Every of this codes but no-one of them works....

This works

```
actions.move_to_element(element).perform()
```

partially because the checkbox appear to have the mouse on it , but it doesn't click , can you help me ?

Comment: Can you share page URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chaining your actions together might help solve this problem. Combine `move_to_element` action with `click` before calling the `perform()` method.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
element = driver.find_element_by_id("order_terms")
actions = ActionChains(driver)
action.move_to_element(element).click(element).perform()
```

OR simply

```
action.move_to_element(element).click().perform()
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the *HTML* you have shared to invoke `click()` on the *checkbox* you can use either of the following solutions:

- `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("label.has-checkbox.terms input.checkbox#order_terms").click()
  ```
- `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[@class='has-checkbox terms']//input[@class='checkbox' and @id='order_terms']").click()
  ```

---

### Update

As you are seeing the error **Other element would receive the click** you can adopt either of the following solutions:

- Induce *WebDriverWait*:

  - `CSS_SELECTOR`:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "label.has-checkbox.terms input.checkbox#order_terms"))).click()
    ```
  - `XPATH`:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//label[@class='has-checkbox terms']//input[@class='checkbox' and @id='order_terms']"))).click()
    ```
- Using *WebDriverWait* and *ActionChains*:

  - `CSS_SELECTOR`:

    ```
    myElement = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "label.has-checkbox.terms input.checkbox#order_terms")))
    ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(myElement).click(myElement).perform()
    ```
  - `XPATH`:

    ```
    myElement = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//label[@class='has-checkbox terms']//input[@class='checkbox' and @id='order_terms']")))
    ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(myElement).click(myElement).perform()
    ```

Comment: it says :  Message: unknown error: Element <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" name="order[terms]" id="order_terms" style="position: absolute; top: -20%; left: -20%; display: block; width: 140%; height: 140%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px; opacity: 0;"> is not clickable at point (532, 511). Other element would receive the click: <ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: -20%; left: -20%; display: block; width: 140%; height: 140%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: rgb(255, 255, 25); border: 0px; opacity: 0;"></ins>

Comment: @Marià Checkout my updated answer and let me know the status